# Updating last but one record -- can not find syntax error in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I need this query - update last but one record.

```
UPDATE changes SET checked='' WHERE item_id = 119898 AND type = 'example_edit' AND checked != 'restored' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

Database echos:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 1' at line 1
```

What is wrong near 1?

Comment: Are you sure its the query cause that error ? maybe there is another query in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard update staement

```
 UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
        SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
        [WHERE where_condition]
        [ORDER BY ...]
        [LIMIT row_count]
```

for your case try this

```
UPDATE changes SET checked='' WHERE item_id = 119898 AND type = 'example_edit' AND checked != 'restored' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Try it will really help you, code tested.
Limit in update can only use row counting not 1,1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT can be used with UPDATE but with the row count only. Refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).

> The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.

So this query should work-

```
 UPDATE 
  changes 
SET
  checked = '' 
WHERE item_id = 119898 
  AND TYPE = 'example_edit' 
  AND checked != 'restored' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: So, there is no way to update *last but one* record. Then, I will do it in two queries, select id, and then update.